# Scriptable Trigger After Line Level Landed Cost Entry on Item Receipt

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a scenario where I want to capture data entered on an Item Receipt immediately after the user keys line level Landed Costs into the sub-record via the inventory detail popup or Landed Cost popup. The scenario is to display real-time actual landed costs.

[image: Landed Cost Icon]

Thus far there does not appear to be a `fieldChanged` or `postSourcing` client-script trigger occurring after the user adds costs in the popup.

Comment: Hi Steve! Were you able to resolve this issue yet?

Comment: Sadly, no. Thus far only able to do what i need after submit. Not ideal since I want real-time, but ....